# C++17 for_each parallel

Tags: c++, loops, parallel-processing, c++17

I would like to ask how can I parallelize the following loop.
It is currently crashing. I tried to search and most answers show that the problem is that I am using `std::vector`. I tried to make a fixed-sized `std::vector`. But the application still crashes. Could you tell me what is wrong in the following loop?

```
    std::vector<int> a(pairsListFlags.size());
    std::generate(a.begin(), a.end(), [n = 0]() mutable { return n++; });
    

    std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, std::begin(a), std::end(a), [&](int i) {

        int a = pairsList[i * 2];
        int b = pairsList[i * 2 + 1];
        if (getCollisionOpenNurbs(OBB[a], OBB[b])) {   //Check OBB collision +4-6 ms  
            if (FaceFace(P[a], P[b], Pl[a], Pl[b])) {//Check polygon intersection +20 ms
                pairsListFlags[i] = 1;
                
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: You are concurrently accessing a non-atomic variable (`counter`) and that's undefined behavior. Other than that we would need to know what's going on in all the functions that are called in the lambda.

Comment: The getCollisionOpenNurbs method checks if 2 boxes collide. The FaceFace method employs clipper library for 2d polyline intersection. How should I know if these functions are not safe for parallel loops? What should I avoid?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not *embarrassingly parallel* and so you should not use `std::for_each` here (at least not without synchronisation mechanisms or atomics which would be inefficient). Instead, you can perform a **reduction using `std::reduce`**. Here is an example:

```cpp
std::vector<int> a(pairsListFlags.size());
std::generate(a.begin(), a.end(), [n = 0]() mutable { return n++; });
int counter = std::reduce(std::execution::par_unseq, std::begin(a), std::end(a), 0, [&](int i) {
    int a = pairsList[i * 2];
    int b = pairsList[i * 2 + 1];
    if (getCollisionOpenNurbs(OBB[a], OBB[b])) {   //Check OBB collision +4-6 ms  
        if (FaceFace(P[a], P[b], Pl[a], Pl[b])) {  //Check polygon intersection +20 ms
            pairsListFlags[i] = 1;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Note that you should be careful about *false sharing* on `pairsListFlags` since it can decrease a bit the performance of the resulting code (but have no impact on the result).

Comment: I think I can skip completely counter. Would this reduce loop will terminate after first boolean true ? I deleted from original post since it is confusing.

Comment: Ok this change the problem. Without `counter`, the reduction is not useful anymore. Note that `getCollisionOpenNurbs` and `FaceFace` needs to be thread safe (and if possible lock free, or even better: wait free). The reduction will not stop early, all the integer values will be computed and summed. Note that the return value is an int and not a bool. If you want to stop the loop earlier and test if any check is true, then you can use `std::any_of`. Besides this, `pairsList.size()` must be at least `a.size()*2` and `P` and `Pl` must have a correct size too. I advise you to use *assertions*.